# Vertical aligning CSS pushes column to left

Tags: css

Finally decided to bite the bullet and ask somewhere, it's been days of pulling my hair out (I don't have an awful lot to begin with these days, so this is distressing :P). I'm using a page-builder (From Elegant themes, included with the DIVI theme) along with some CSS to vertically align an element next to some text on a two column row.

The CSS is as follows:

.MlCentered {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

I've assigned the class to the second column (containing a picture of a waterfall in this example).

When I do this, the column is, for some reason pulled over left, on top of the first column.

The strange thing is, this was working perfectly as of a couple of weeks ago. Not only that but I've alos tested it with different themes and different builders, to no avail. All plugins are disabled, wordpress is up to date, as is the theme. I'm truly stumped.

I've created a page detailing and displaying the problem, here: 
http://headsmartdevelopment.com/vertical-align-issue

This was initially written for the devs at Elegant themes, but they've not been able to give me a non-stock answer.

If this is the wrong place to post, please accept my apologies. I've used the search function to search for both the issue and the CSS specifically but couldn't find anything.

If someone could just let me know what I'm doing wrong, or point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful.

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give that element a `right` value.

I think maybe your still expecting the `float left` to align it. But once you position an element `absolute`, the element is taken out of the flow of normal elements.

```
right: 0;
```

Comment: Nath, Thank you! You've saved the remaining hairs on my head, and you've allowed some dude in his room to finally get some sleep. Legend. Thanks!